# Javascript/ variable place/ what is wrong with the code

Tags: javascript

I want to write a Generator for Fibonacci numbers in Javascript;
0,1,1,2,5,7,12..... (to make the sequence you have to add the last two numbers)
But I have this problem when I assign the the output.length to a variable the code is not working, if I write it down straight instead of "newNumber" the code down is however working, but I don't understand what is wrong with the first one. Is it something wrong with the place of the variables?

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  var output = [];
  var lastNumber = output[output.length - 1];
  var nPrev = output[output.length - 2];
  var newNumber = lastNumber + nPrev;

  if (n === 1) {
    output = [0];
  } else if (n === 2) {
    output = [0, 1];
  } else {
    output = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      output.push(newNumber);
    }
  }
  return output
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(5));
```

Comment: When you assign `output.length` to a variable it captures the length *at the time of the assignment*, it does not "auto update" when the length changes. When you insert it directly the `.length` property access will capture *that* value at that moment in time, since you're changing the length of output by pushing on to it.

Comment: and as well `output.push(newNumber);` will keep pushing in the output array the same value (NaN) again and again because you are supposed to populate the `newNumber` variable at each iteration. I have a suggestion that is very very general... if you use the statement `debugger;` anywhere in your code and you load the page with the developer tools open (and the debugger tab active), the debugger will break at that exact point and you can see with your own eyes what's going on step by step

Comment: Thank you sooo much Jared Smith and Diego D!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function fibonacciGen(n) {
      const output = [0, 1];

  // Return an empty array if n is less than 1
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  }


  // If n is 1 or 2, we can return the array now
  if (n <2) {
    return output;
  }

  // Loop through the remaining numbers in the sequence
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    // Calculate the next number in the sequence
    let lastNumber = output[output.length - 1];
    let nPrev = output[output.length - 2];
    let newNumber = lastNumber + nPrev;

    // Add the new number to the output array
     output.push(newNumber);
  }



  // Return the output array
  return output;
}

console.log(fibonacciGen(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare your logic of next term in loop because first time length of output is zero

```js
function fibonacciGenerator (n) {
    var output =[]; 
    
    if (n < 1) {
      return [];
    }
    if (n===1){
        output=[0];
    }
    else if (n===2){
        output=[0,1];
    }
    else{ 
        output=[0,1];
        for( var i = 2; i < n; i++){
            var lastNumber=output[output.length-1];
            var nPrev=output[output.length-2];
            var newNumber=lastNumber+nPrev;
            output.push(newNumber);
        }
    }
    return output  
}
```